# How to create a custom container element for Orchard Layout?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I'm using Orchard 1.9.3 and followed some tutorials on how to create a custom normal Element in Orchard. I couldn't find any specifically on creating container elements so I dug around a bit in the source and this is what I have so far:

**Elements/Procedure.cs**

```cs
public class Procedure : Container
{
    public override string Category
    {
        get { return "Content"; }
    }

    public override string ToolboxIcon
    {
        get { return "\uf0cb"; }
    }

    public override LocalizedString Description
    {
        get { return T("A collection of steps."); }
    }

    public override bool HasEditor
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

**Drivers/ProcedureElementDriver.cs**

```cs
public class ProcedureElementDriver : ElementDriver<Procedure> {}
```

**Services/ProcedureModelMap**

```cs
public class ProcedureModelMap : LayoutModelMapBase<Procedure> {}
```

**Views/LayoutEditor.Template.Procedure**

```cs
@using Orchard.Layouts.ViewModels;
<div class="layout-element-wrapper" ng-class="{'layout-container-empty': getShowChildrenPlaceholder()}">
<ul class="layout-panel layout-panel-main">
    <li class="layout-panel-item layout-panel-label">Procedure</li>
    @Display()
    @Display(New.LayoutEditor_Template_Properties(ElementTypeName: "procedure"))
    <li class="layout-panel-item layout-panel-action" title="@T("Delete {{element.contentTypeLabel.toLowerCase()}} (Del)")" ng-click="delete(element)"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></li>
    <li class="layout-panel-item layout-panel-action" title="@T("Move {{element.contentTypeLabel.toLowerCase()}} up (Ctrl+Up)")" ng-click="element.moveUp()" ng-class="{disabled: !element.canMoveUp()}"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></li>
    <li class="layout-panel-item layout-panel-action" title="@T("Move {{element.contentTypeLabel.toLowerCase()}} down (Ctrl+Down)")" ng-click="element.moveDown()" ng-class="{disabled: !element.canMoveDown()}"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></li>
</ul>
<div class="layout-container-children-placeholder">
    @T("Drag a steps here.")
</div>
@Display(New.LayoutEditor_Template_Children())
```

All of this is more or less copied from the Row element. I now have a `Procedure` element that I can drag from the Toolbox onto my Layout but it is not being rendered with my template, even though I can override the templates for the other layout elements this way, and I still can't drag any children into it. I had hoped that simply inheriting from `Container` would have made that possible.

I essentially just want to make a more restrictive Row and Column pair to apply some custom styling to a list of arbitrary content. How can I tell Orchard that a Procedure can only be contained in a Column and that it should accept `Steps` (or some other element) as children?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out how to make container and containable elements from looking at [Mainbit's layout module](https://github.com/MainBit/MainBit.Layouts).
The container elements require some additional Angular code to make them work. **I still need help figuring out how to limit which elements can be contained!**

**Scripts/LayoutEditor.js**

I had to extend the LayoutEditor module with a directive to hold all of the Angular stuff pertaining to my element:

```js
angular
.module("LayoutEditor")
.directive("orcLayoutProcedure", ["$compile", "scopeConfigurator", "environment",
    function ($compile, scopeConfigurator, environment) {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: { element: "=" },
            controller: ["$scope", "$element",
                function ($scope, $element) {
                    scopeConfigurator.configureForElement($scope, $element);
                    scopeConfigurator.configureForContainer($scope, $element);
                    $scope.sortableOptions["axis"] = "y";
                }
            ],
            templateUrl: environment.templateUrl("Procedure"),
            replace: true
        };
    }
]);
```

**Scripts/Models.js**

And a Provider for Orchard's LayoutEditor to use:

```js
var LayoutEditor;
(function (LayoutEditor) {

LayoutEditor.Procedure = function (data, htmlId, htmlClass, htmlStyle, isTemplated, children) {
    LayoutEditor.Element.call(this, "Procedure", data, htmlId, htmlClass, htmlStyle, isTemplated);
    LayoutEditor.Container.call(this, ["Grid", "Content"], children);

    //this.isContainable = true;
    this.dropTargetClass = "layout-common-holder";

    this.toObject = function () {
        var result = this.elementToObject();
        result.children = this.childrenToObject();
        return result;
    };
};

LayoutEditor.Procedure.from = function (value) {
    var result = new LayoutEditor.Procedure(
        value.data,
        value.htmlId,
        value.htmlClass,
        value.htmlStyle,
        value.isTemplated,
        LayoutEditor.childrenFrom(value.children));
    result.toolboxIcon = value.toolboxIcon;
    result.toolboxLabel = value.toolboxLabel;
    result.toolboxDescription = value.toolboxDescription;
    return result;
};

LayoutEditor.registerFactory("Procedure", function (value) {
    return LayoutEditor.Procedure.from(value);
});

})(LayoutEditor || (LayoutEditor = {}));
```

This specifically is the line that tells the element what it can contain:

```js
LayoutEditor.Container.call(this, ["Grid", "Content"], children);
```

**ResourceManifest.cs**

Then I made a resource manifest to easily make these available in Orchard's module.

```cs
public class ResourceManifest : IResourceManifestProvider
{
    public void BuildManifests(ResourceManifestBuilder builder)
    {
        var manifest = builder.Add();
        manifest.DefineScript("MyModule.Models").SetUrl("Models.js").SetDependencies("Layouts.LayoutEditor");
        manifest.DefineScript("MyModule.LayoutEditors").SetUrl("LayoutEditor.js").SetDependencies("Layouts.LayoutEditor", "MyModule.Models");
    }
}
```

By default, `.SetUrl()` points to the /Scripts folder in your module/theme.

**Handlers/LayoutEditorShapeEventHandler.cs**

Finally, I added this handler to load my scripts on the admin pages that use the Layout Editor.

```cs
public class LayoutEditorShapeEventHandler : IShapeTableProvider
{
    private readonly Work<IResourceManager> _resourceManager;
    public LayoutEditorShapeEventHandler(Work<IResourceManager> resourceManager)
    {
        _resourceManager = resourceManager;
    }

    public void Discover(ShapeTableBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Describe("EditorTemplate").OnDisplaying(context =>
        {
            if (context.Shape.TemplateName != "Parts.Layout")
                return;

            _resourceManager.Value.Require("script", "MyModule.LayoutEditors");
        });
    }
}
```

Hopefully, this will help someone out in the future. However, I still don't know how to make it so that my Container will *only* contain my Containable or that my Containable will *only* allow itself to be contained by my Container. It seems like adjusting `LayoutEditor.Container.call(this, ["Grid", "Content"], children);` would have been enough to achieve this, but it's not. More help is still welcome.

Comment: They and then I mean the Developers Team should have done what you did but You have to buy the book from Sipke to know the Internals of Layout creation. I think that breaks with "real" Open Source. I think Orchard CMS is moving in a wrong direction that way. Another thing is that the Layout Module is not ment to be "Extendable" by nature. A module has to do that "trick" in some way. I don't know if thats the "right" way to implement such basic features in a CMS system. Question: anyone knows how to implement an bootstrap OffCanvas draggable in Orchard CMS?

Comment: I have added an "answer", so I could explain my solution to your restricting placement problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thank you for this answer. I found it really helpful. Still, I ended up having problems to restrict where my container element could be placed and what could be placed inside of it.

I've noticed that those restrictions are made based on the category of the element. Canvas, Grid, Row, Column or Content.
Orchard goes through all categories and runs some code to understand where the items inside that category can be placed.
Anything outside Orchard's Layout Category is a Content. If you have a lot of different custom categories for a variety of custom elements, they are still Contents in Orchard's eyes. So... For every category you have, Orchard's gonna run some code and say that every item inside that category is actually a Content and they all end up having the same placement rules.

I didn't want any of my custom container to be placeable inside another custom container, and I didn't want anything other then content being placed inside my custom containers, so I ended up doing the following steps:

1. Go to your Procedure.cs file and change your class' category.

   **public override string Category => "Container";**
2. Go to your Models.js file and change the value in the "dropTargetClass" property.

   **this.dropTargetClass = 'layout-common-holder layout-customcontainer';**
3. Go to the LayoutEditor.Template.ToolboxGroup.cshtml file (you could create your own in your theme) and change the value in the "ui-sortable" attribute in the ul element.

   **ui-sortable="category.name == 'Container' ?
   $parent.getSortableOptions(category.name) : $parent.getSortableOptions('Content')"**
4. Go to the Toolbox.js file and edit the "getSortableOptions" function, so it contains a case for your newly created "Container" category. Pay attention to where the "layout-customcontainer" class appears bellow. I wanted to remove the ability of placing grids, and other layout elements inside my container, so I had to change their cases too.

   ```
   switch (type) {
       case "Container":
           parentClasses = [".layout-column", ".layout-common-holder:not(.layout-customcontainer)"];
           placeholderClasses = "layout-element layout-container ui-sortable-placeholder";
           break;
       case "Grid":
           parentClasses = [".layout-canvas", ".layout-column", ".layout-common-holder:not(.layout-customcontainer)"];
           placeholderClasses = "layout-element layout-container layout-grid ui-sortable-placeholder";
           break;
       case "Row":
           parentClasses = [".layout-grid"];
           placeholderClasses = "layout-element layout-container layout-row row ui-sortable-placeholder";
           break;
       case "Column":
           parentClasses = [".layout-row:not(.layout-row-full)"];
           placeholderClasses = "layout-element layout-container layout-column ui-sortable-placeholder";
           floating = true; // To ensure a smooth horizontal-list reordering. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable#floating
           break;
       case "Content":
           parentClasses = [".layout-canvas", ".layout-column", ".layout-common-holder"];
           placeholderClasses = "layout-element layout-content ui-sortable-placeholder";
           break;
       case "Canvas":
           parentClasses = [".layout-canvas", ".layout-column", ".layout-common-holder:not(.layout-container)"];
           placeholderClasses = "layout-element layout-container layout-grid ui-sortable-placeholder";
           break;}
   ```
5. Run the Gulpfile.js task, so your changes are placed inside Orchard's LayoutEditor.js file.

Now, you have a container element with some custom restrictions.

I hope it's not to late to be useful to you.